# Can I remove this logo and the university name in this beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, presentations

Here's the template I've found:
https://www.overleaf.com/10676029dhrjkbgszmhh#/40012310/
Can I remove it form the first slide?

Comment: Please post the TeX code of your best attempt here.  That link may change, and few people will follow the link and dig into what you want.

Comment: And most people will tell you to avoid templates like the plague. Your life will be easier without them.

Comment: Other people will tell you that templates can be very useful, the plague is extinct and does not need to be avoided. But: some templates are _really_ crappy. Don't use those ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the logo definition by using

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fibeamer@includeLogo[1][]{}
\makeatother
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[faculty=ped]{fibeamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,portuges]{babel}     

\title{Presentation Title - template de slides bonito e que parece código}
\subtitle{Presentation Subtitle}
\author{Author's Name}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fibeamer@includeLogo[1][]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]