# Is it possible to add more than one listing code to my frame?

Tags: beamer, errors

Here's my (it's not working) code:

```
      \documentclass{beamer}
      \usetheme[faculty=ped]{fibeamer}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage{verbatim}
      \usepackage[main=english,portuges]{babel}        
      \usepackage{ragged2e}  
      \usepackage{tikz}     
      \usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, backgrounds}  
      \usepackage{listings}  
      \frenchspacing
      \makeatletter
     \renewcommand\fibeamer@includeLogo[1][]{}
      \makeatother
      \begin{document}      
        \begin{darkframes}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Variáveis}{Alguns Tipos de Variáveis}
\item int

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,tabsize=2]
  code1
\end{lstlisting}

\item float

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,tabsize=2]
  code2
\end{lstlisting}

\item bool

\end{frame}     

\end{darkframes}      

  \end{document}
```

I get the error:

> Runaway argument?
>   Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
>    
>                      \par 
>   l.123       \end{frame}

Comment: This is now your 7th question on the site, and none of them have included a Minimal Working Example document to show people what you are doing. Please don't do this. Include your code fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Comment: Should it be like this?

Comment: Well that's compilable but not really minimal. It includes other code that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. So eliminate any unneeded packages and code until you have a document that compiles (even with an error) to show the problem.

Comment: Well, I think it should be correct now, but there are some files within the project. What is the best thing to do in this case?

Comment: You should change the language options of babel to the language you actually use, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386998/36296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` is missing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}  

\begin{document}      

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Variáveis}{Alguns Tipos de Variáveis}

\begin{itemize}
\item int

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,tabsize=2]
  code1
\end{lstlisting}

\item float

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,tabsize=2]
  code2
\end{lstlisting}

\item bool
\end{itemize}   

\end{frame}      

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Variáveis}{Alguns Tipos de Variáveis}
```

and use `lstlisting` without `itemize`:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Variáveis}{Alguns Tipos de Variáveis}
\textbullet\ int

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,tabsize=2]
  code1
\end{lstlisting}

\textbullet\ float

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,tabsize=2]
  code2
\end{lstlisting}

\textbullet\ bool

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Now the error message changed:

(no line number):
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ped-pdflatex.tex

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: It works!
Why can't we use itemize? The little circles are slightly different and white instead of orange. Is it possible to make the circles orange again?